# Added photo does not fit in the frame of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, photo, xcode5

please help to push added photo in the frame of UIImageView. The photo doesn't fit in the frame. I have made all the same like in the "IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" chapter 12 "Camera". Before adding photo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0uypvspuhvlkm2/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-27%20at%205.08.39%20PM.jpg After adding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6qffb1l941cb0v/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-27%20at%205.09.02%20PM.jpg I've tried `setContentMode` for UIImageView – doesn't works. This is my code:

```
#pragma mark UIActionSheetDelegate

- (IBAction)displayActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Take photo", @"Choose photo from gallery", nil];

    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self takePhoto];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self choosePhoto];
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)takePhoto {
    UIImagePickerController *pickerControllerTakePhoto = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [pickerControllerTakePhoto setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [pickerControllerTakePhoto setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pickerControllerTakePhoto animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)choosePhoto {
    UIImagePickerController *pickerControllerChoosePhoto = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [pickerControllerChoosePhoto setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [pickerControllerChoosePhoto setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pickerControllerChoosePhoto animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *myPhoto = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [photoView setImage:myPhoto];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

My 'plus' or 'add' button calls action sheet with dialog, so I choose the photo from gallery and result is like on second screenshot.

Comment: Is `photoView` really the UIImageView?

Comment: Yes, `__weak IBOutlet UIImageView *photoView;`

Comment: Second screenshot: is this you?

Comment: What is the frame of photoView?

Comment: How did you add photoView to the view hierarchy? What is its superview?

Comment: The frame is `photoView.layer.cornerRadius = 13.0; photoView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` in `- (void)viewDidLoad`. UIImageView <- custom table view cell <- table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image views properties:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Both can be set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Doesn't work, have set property and added code in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the line of code that disturbed me, this all because of my custom cells which I put in order to my tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        photoView = (UIImageView *)[photoCell viewWithTag:1]; // this is the first custom cell in my tableview and this line which I put on the model of the book isn't needed
        cell = photoCell;
...............................
```